# Smooth out MantaFlow Fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm creating a fluid simulation with Mantaflow and I am trying to understand why my result is so jagged. I've tried applying a Smooth modifier to the liquid object but it doesn't seem to result in a huge difference.

It takes a long time for my machine to bake the mesh and so it's difficult to narrow down which one of the settings produces a favourable result. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: How many voxels do you have on edge? The default 32 is way too few.

Answer (score 0):

Up the resolution divisions to say, 64 for a slow computer. I am pretty sure narrow bandwidth of 4 would help as well in the domain settings.